# how to get kivy run in a virtual box

Tags: python-3.x, virtualbox, kivy

Hej

I try to play a litte around with Ubuntu 14 LTS 64Bit at Oracle VM on Windows 7. Installing kivy for python3 works fine. BUT when I want to create the App in python I got following error:

```
[[1;32mINFO[0m   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/stj/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-06-04_0.txt
[[1;32mINFO[0m   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[[1;32mINFO[0m   ] [Python      ] v3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[[1;32mINFO[0m   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[[1;32mINFO[0m   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pil (img_pygame, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[[1;31mCRITICAL[0m] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

pygame - ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pygame

x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[[1;31mCRITICAL[0m] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

pygame is installed and I think the packages for the x11 window manager. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have pygame for python3 installed in the same python installation you were trying kivy with?

Comment: I think so. Used ´sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame´ to install pygame

Comment: thanks inclement - I checked the my installation of pygame and rebuild it
now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pygame installation for python3 was the problem use following code to solve it:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
cd pygame
python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
cd ..
sudo rm -rf pygame
```

based on [kivy installation notes](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer)